# Angular 15: Using hostDirectives: [NgIf] is throwing No provider for TemplateRef found

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular2-directives

I am attempting to leverage `NgIf` as a host directive to show and hide content. There are a number of blog posts that are all doing the same pattern and there is no mention of this issue or how to work around it. I have tried a number of things including adding NgIf as an import and even a provider in the module with no luck.

My directive works fine until I start to add `NgIf` as a `hostDirectives` entry you can see here everything works fine until you uncomment `lines 63,69,78`. If you open the console you will see the `TemplateRef error`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-15-directive-composition-api-48mby7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Examples of the pattern of leveraging NgIf in your custom directive.

https://dev.to/this-is-angular/directives-in-practice-user-role-based-element-control-49id

https://netbasal.com/making-dry-conditional-structural-directives-using-angular-directive-composition-api-bc346672445d

What am I missing here? I have dealt with this error for years and generally its a quick fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Do not provide the `ngIf` in your component. Create a structural directive that provides the `ngIf` in `hostProviders` exactly as in the examples above.

**Analysis**

In your code you are providing `ngIf`in a component and not in a directive as in the examples you have posted. The [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-shorthand) `ngIf` [depends on TemplateRef](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L162) `(ng-template)` and that is why you are getting an error.

It works only with structural directives because elements that use structural directives prefixed by `*` are converted by angular to an `ng-template` element which then allow the structural directives like `ngIf` and `ngFor` to change the dom layout.

Here is a [working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bneepg?file=src%2Fcustom.directive.ts)

Comment: Were you able to create an example of directive that uses ngIf as a hostDirective? Similar to here: https://dev.to/this-is-angular/directives-in-practice-user-role-based-element-control-49id

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working example

Comment: I updated my stackblitz example. I do see standalone to standalone does not throw the error. I am running Version 15 and the components are not standalone. The example I added is throwing the same error. Do you see anything that jumps out as the part I am missing? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7wt4d8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Resolved: I did not need the `hostDirectives` in the component. I simply needed to import into my non standalone components parent module.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f3djmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thank you Mehyar